# How to define variable with M2E builds? (equivalent to -Dvar=value)

Tags: eclipse, variables, build, m2e

I use variables inside some of my `pom.xml` files like that:

```xml
<project ...>
    ...
    <properties>
        <password>someValue</password>
```

This is later used with the `maven-resources-plugin` in order to generate some of my files with correct password.

The advantage is I can build my production package like that: `mvn package -Dpassword=someOtherValue`

The problem is when I use [m2e-wtp](http://www.eclipse.org/m2e-wtp/) to build my project (which is a war), I can only define the maven profile I want to activate (Project > Properties > Maven > Active Maven Profiles).

I'm using the Maven build which is provided when you "Import > Existing Maven Projects".

I didn't find the way to define the any build variable... any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

Keeping variables which are scoped to a build profile works as long as they're unmutable (e.g., dependency versions), due to the way Maven works.

What I'd suggest would be to place your build-dependant variables in your `.m2/settings.xml` file. m2eclipse will happily read them and apply to your build, and this file is quite portable, so you can install into other machines.

It also applies to profiles, so you could combine into a single file all the relevant variables for your environments.

Comment: I think this is the only way as I saw it [here](http://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/m2e-dev/msg01216.html) you're right... I must test your answer & then I will accept it thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Did you try setting the parameters in the Maven build configuration?[image: Parameter settings for M2E builds]

This seems exactly the same thing you describe here.

Comment: The question was about using the Maven build which is provided when you "Import > Existing Maven Projects". When doing that, you don't have a "Maven Build" configuration created, you handle your Maven project with the properties of the project (> Maven) and the right-click menu of the project > Maven...

Comment: Ok, I did not paid enough attention. Sorry, I cannot help then.